# How can I get the name of grouping columns from a Pandas GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Foo=['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], Bar=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

i.e.:

```
   Bar Foo
0    1   A
1    2   A
2    3   B
3    4   B
```

Then I create a pandas.GroupBy object:

```
g = df.groupby('Foo')
```

How can I get, from `g`, the fact that `g` is grouped by a column originally named `Foo`?

If I do `g.groups` I get:

```
{'A': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'B': Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')}
```

That tells me the *values* that the `Foo` column takes ('A' and 'B') but not the original column name.

Now, I can just do something like:

```
g.first().index.name
```

But it seems odd that there's not an attribute of `g` with the group name in it, so I feel like I must be missing something. In particular, if `g` was grouped by multiple columns, then the above doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Foo=['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], Baz=['C', 'D', 'C', 'D'], Bar=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
g = df.groupby(['Foo', 'Baz'])
g.first().index.name # returns None, because it's a MultiIndex
g.first().index.names # returns ['Foo', 'Baz']
```

For context, I am trying to do some plotting with a grouped dataframe, and I want to be able to label each facet (which is plotting a single group) with the name of that group as well as the group label.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query `GroupBy.BaseGrouper.names` to get a list of all groupers:

```
df.groupby('Foo').grouper.names
```

Which gives,

```
['Foo']
```

Comment: Nice! Too bad it seems to be completely undocumented :(

Comment: @bwk Indeed. It isn't at all documented anywhere. It's more like a metadata object for groupby objects (weird that they'd have it, but judging by this question I suppose there's some use to it).